# How to display certain field in cakephp use scaffold

Tags: cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

i want to display certain field in database use scaffold , please help me

EX:

```
     Product  Model has property is ("name", "description", "price", "created_at")
     and i want to display field 'name','description' and 'price' use scaffold
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure its a good way to do this but it will work for you---
Just define a table schema on  model class.
Like your-

## Product.php

```
public $_schema = array(
        'name' => array(
            'type' => 'string',
            'length' => 30
        ),
        'description' => array(
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
        'price' => array(
            'type' => 'float'
        )

);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Fazal Rasel, i want to created_at in database , but i don't want to display it in form or index when use scaffold.